# It's possible to integrate a no-compatible EVM network?

Tags: gnosis-safe

The question it's just that, I was making research about possible integration with the Zenon network that it's not EVM compatible.

I'm pretty sure that isn't possible, but maybe someone had this kind of implementation.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnosis Safe is built only for EVM compatible blockchains.